# SKView textureFromNode resulting image blurry?

Tags: sprite-kit

I've observed when taking a SKSpriteNode that is relatively sharp, and taking a snapshot with SKView's textureFromNode the resulting image is blurry. This is even taking into account the Texture Filtering (Which is set to Linear at default). I was wondering if this working as intended or if there is more to SKView then meets the eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a "snapshot" image of the current `SKView` and `SKScene` contents, you might be better off looking at the new method `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`. This works well in my testing, albeit a little slower than expected. I think the problem you're seeing is that the size of the resulting `SKTexture` returned from `textureFromNode:` is based off of the node's `calculateAccumulatedFrame` which may or may not be the size you want/expect. It could also just be rendering the texture correctly, and you're just seeing the re-rendered form of the already rendered sprite (basically, getting more lossy every time it's rendered again, which logically makes sense).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is not SpriteKit native, which is fine except that many people are using the textureFromNode to draw textures of large sprite hierarchies (particle systems etc) that haven't been added to the scene yet so as to display thousands of sprites in a single draw. Using drawViewHierarchyInRect requires the sprites to be drawn before the texture is created. This blur is a real problem. I think you're right about the frame size being the issue, or something similar.

Comment: As I wrote elsewhere, you should use `SKView textureFromNode:crop:` to avoid artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
```

With this mode you get less blur, more pixelated. As described in the reference for `SKTexture` :

`SKTextureFilteringNearest`

Each pixel is drawn using the nearest point in the texture. This mode is faster, but the results are often pixelated.

I used this with some code I had for line drawing with `SKShapeNode`. Before setting the `filteringMode` property as such, my lines became more and more blurry over time. With this setting and even with the `SKShapeNode` `antialiased` property set to `YES`, it remained crisp and not blurry at all.

Not sure of your current implementation, but maybe this will help you.

Comment: Brilliant - worked a charm for me - didn't have to alter the shape node's antialias either. If I don't do this I get a blurry texture.

Answer (score 0):

```
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
```

This didn't help in my case. I had to turn antialiased OFF on my SKShapeNode. And then textureFromNode(grid -> SKShapeNode) resulted with sharp texture/SKSpriteNode.

```
grid.antialiased = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered another way of improving the fidelity of textures created from ShapeNodes.

Create your shape at x2 its size and width. 
Create all the fonts and other shapes at the same oversized ratio. 
Make sure your positioning is relative to this overall size, (e.g. don't use absolute sizes, use relative sizes to the container.)

When you create the texture as a sprite it'll be huge - but then apply

```
sprite.scale = 0.5; // if you were using 2x
```

(Note, if you have child elements, scale might not be the best solution - setting size will be better).

I've found this makes it look much higher resolution, no graininess, no fuzziness on fonts, sharp corners.

I also used `tex.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringLinear;`

[Edit - I previously had this as SKTextureFilteringNearest - but that produces artefacts on straight lines - Linear now produces good straight lines].

Answer (score 0):

```
texture.filteringMode = .nearest
```

potentially this can cause pixelation, you can also try

```
texture.filteringMode = .linear
```